# textarea not resizing or listening to CSS

Tags: html, css, textarea

I'm trying to make a custom sized text area in HTML, but it doesn't seem to be working. I set it inside a class so it would I could set CSS element to it, but it doesn't seem to work.

```css
.textareas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  font-size: 16px;
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="textareas"><textarea></textarea></div>
```

It seems to create the box I make, but the actual textarea remains unchanged and is still small and stuck as the default one.

Comment: Your div has the class, not the textarea. Try `<div><textarea class="textareas"></textarea></div>`

Answer (score 1):

Check below code

```css
.textareas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  font-size: 16px;
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<div><textarea  class="textareas"></textarea></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue after reviewing some other examples. I removed the class entirely and gave the textarea an ID so it can be called in CSS

```
HTML:
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
```

```
CSS:
textarea#text{
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  font-size: 16px;
  resize: none;
}
```

Comment: same result as the answer by @Umesh